# Why are FallingSand entities not showing correct blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I summon FallingSand entities in Minecraft, strange things happen when I make them from water, flowing water, lava, flowing lava, and stained glass blocks.

With liquids, they simply are invisible. I know they're there because I pressed F3+B to check the hitbox.

With stained glass, they create a block with a single, solid colour with no transparency.

Why is this so?

Comment: Are you asking why FallingSand entities are transparent?

Comment: No, i am asking why they are NOT transparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's the way it was programmed. I don't think there is a way around it without hacking or mods. Why does it matter anyway? Why would you need falling stained glass?

Comment: I wanted to make  a washing machine that teleports a water/blue stained glass block to and from it when it turns on/off

Comment: just use /setblock

Comment: I wanted to make it so there is a slab with a trapdoor attached and when a lever is flipped, the water appears  _inside_ the slab block